# Ошибка при проверке условия в цикле

Tags: java

Цикл работает некорректно.
Нужно проверить текущий файл на проверки если все проверки успешны => кладем файл в очередь.

```
boolean checkFiles = true;
for (Checker currentChecker : checkers) {
    while (checkFiles) {
            if (!currentChecker.check(currentFile)) {
                    heckFiles = false;
                    break;
            }
    }
    if (checkFiles) {
            queue.put(currentFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то у вас всё сложно. Давайте попробуем проще:

```
var checksPassed = true;
for (Checker currentChecker : checkers) {
    if (!currentChecker.check(currentFile)) {
        checksPassed = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (checksPassed)
    queue.put(currentFile);
```

Comment: спасибо, а то такая каша уже в голове.

Comment: @nazar_art: пожалуйста!